# kubernetes virtual service for Zuul Proxy fails without port forwarding

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, istio

I have a virtual service in kubernetes as defined in the following file,

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: {{ .Chart.Name }}-vs
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  hosts:
    - {{ .Values.virtualservice.host }}
    - {{ .Chart.Name }}.default.svc.cluster.local
  gateways:
    - {{ .Values.virtualservice.gateway }}
    - mesh
  http:
    - route:
        - destination:
            host: {{ .Chart.Name }}.default.svc.cluster.local
            port:
              number: {{ .Values.service.port }}
      corsPolicy:
        allowOrigin:
          - '*'
        allowMethods:
          - OPTIONS
          - GET
          - POST
          - PUT
          - DELETE
        allowCredentials: true
        allowHeaders:
          - '*'
        maxAge: "24h"
```

My actual service works fine when I port forward to it. It's a java app serving HTTP only.

However, when I try to hit it using `HTTPS` via the virtual service as defined above, it fails.
The static pages load fine. But if hit something that causes the app to go backend and access another service, I get a failure.
The app is actually a Zuul proxy and needs to hit backend services.

I am not able to figure out how to debug this or what could be causing this issue.

thanks

**EDIT**

A strange thing I noticed. All the services including the api-gw are listening on port 8080. They are all `Spring-boot` apps.

`Fails`:

- API-gw service, SpringBootApp and Docker container and kube service - 8080
- Back-end service, SpringBootApp , Docker container and kube service - 8080

`Succeeds`:

- API-gw service, SpringBootApp and Docker container and kube service - **11243** [*anything except 8080*]
- Back-end service, SpringBootApp , Docker container and kube service - 8080

what's the reason?

thanks

Comment: Could You please provide informations about ports on ingressgateway and your springboot pod when it works and when it's not? istioctl proxy-config listeners <pod>, istioctl proxy-config cluster -n istio-system istio-ingressgateway. Is backend injected?

Comment: when I change the port of the API-gw to 11243, this is what the `listeners` command outputs.Is the envoy listening on all these ports and IPs in one container? [*clipped*]
```
ADDRESS          PORT      TYPE
10.51.1.37       11243     HTTP
..
10.0.0.10        53        TCP
10.0.125.210     80        TCP
10.0.0.1         443       TCP
10.0.230.67      443       TCP
..
10.0.8.156       8080      TCP
..
0.0.0.0          9092      TCP
10.0.63.7        8088      TCP
10.0.77.207      8080      TCP
0.0.0.0          8080      TCP
0.0.0.0          80        TCP
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [medium](https://medium.com/@nepalBrothers/api-gateway-using-spring-boot-zuul-part-1-6fb943c8efb8) and listeners command i think the answer is port collision.

> [image]
>
> API Gateway is a concept of having a single point of entry to access all of the services in the backend.

You shouldn't have the same port on api-gw like on frontend and backend.

> [image]
> API Gateway will run in port 8090
>
> Product will run in port 8080
>
> API Gateway will be configured to redirect all the traffic to the Product service.

So when You changed the port from 8080 to random free port like 11243 it's working properly because there is no port collision between frontend/backend and api gateway.

I hope it will help You. Let me know if You have any more questions.

Comment: thanks for the answer. However these are completely different containers and services. their IPs are diferent too. I don't understand why I have to change the port if the IP is the same

Comment: Hello @user3169330, check out this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57843144), i think in comments there is the answer you're looking for, seems like you can't use same ports for different services because it makes conflict in pilot.

Comment: thanks @jt97 , yes, that's indeed the answer, i.e. the bit about pilot. I found this page as well - https://istio.io/docs/ops/deployment/requirements/ which describes the ports used by istio.